# javascript - object not a function error when evalulating whether something is null

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, conditional-statements, or-operator

I have the following code:

```
console.log(callback);
if (typeof callback != "undefined" || callback != null){
  callback();
}
```

where the console prints out:

```
null
```

but javascript is still attempting to execute the callback() function call. Any idea why?

Comment: simply put `&&` to check if any one is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it should be `&&`, i.e. *logical AND*:

```
if (typeof callback != "undefined" && callback != null) {
    callback();
}
```

But I'd suggest to use check for type "function":

```
if (typeof callback === "function") {
    callback();
}
```

or even shorter:

```
typeof callback === "function" && callback();
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
console.log(callback);
if (!(typeof (callback) == "undefined" || callback == null)){
  callback();
}
```